# How do I update to jupyterlab 4 using the Anaconda distribution?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-lab

I installed the most recent Anaconda distribution of Python that I downloaded here: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.03-1-Linux-x86_64.sh.

I created a new environment named `af` that is a clone of the `base` environment: `conda create --name af --clone base`

I activated this new environment: `conda activate af`

The JupyterLab version in `base` and `af` is 3.5.3, and I want to update it to 4.

```
(af) richard@ms7c90:~$ jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.10.0
ipykernel        : 6.19.2
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 5.2.0
jupyter_server   : 1.23.4
jupyterlab       : 3.5.3
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.5.4
nbformat         : 5.7.0
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : 5.4.0
traitlets        : 5.7.1
```

The [JupyterLab 4 announcement](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-4-0-is-here-388d05e03442) says I should run: `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`.
But this only gets me to 3.6.4.
***How do I update JupyterLab to 4?***

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @a06e No, I will wait for an update on the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: So you're saying that Anaconda has yet to incorporate JupyterLab 4 on their "stable channel" ? So we just wait and eventually we'll get it.

Comment: @a06e Yes. I use Anaconda 2023.03, and my Jupyter Lab version is 3.5.3. https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/release-notes/#release-notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could update after uninstalling the previous version with

```
  pip install -U jupyterlab
```

followed by

```
  pip install jupyterlab
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work with Anaconda? Does it matter that my current installation of JupyterLab is from conda instead of pip?

Comment: This also worked for me, but I am unsure how `pip` removed the `conda`-installed `jupyterlab` package. I will comment if anything breaks.

Comment: This worked for me too, and my JupyterLab was installed on a miniconda env

Comment: It is bad practice to use pip to install packages in a conda environment as it does not check dependencies and will break the conda environment and afterwards any other conda installs will just hang at solving stage. Create a new conda environment if you really need to use pip and dont care if environment gets corrupted. You can read about this in anaconda website blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me : ( **jupyter lab --version** is to be sure if older version of jupyterlab in the current active environment already exist , key command is :  **conda update jupyterlab** )

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user1> jupyter lab --version
3.6.3

(base) PS C:\Users\user1> conda update jupyterlab

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
....

The following packages will be REMOVED:    
....

The following packages will be UPDATED:    
....

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(base) PS C:\Users\user1> jupyter lab --version
4.0.8
```

**If you get:**

```
CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length
```

Try clearing the cache as follow, before doing above (happened to me but after using : **conda clean --all** , above worked.)

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user1> conda clean --all
Will remove 64 (206.8 MB) tarball(s).
Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Will remove 1 index cache(s).
Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Will remove 54 (522.4 MB) package(s).
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

Answer (score 0):

### For Anaconda users do not use pip.

If your Conda environment is not upgrading to jupyterlab 4, uninstall the current version first either through Anaconda Navigator or a command prompt with the `conda` command. Once the older version is removed, jupyterlab 4 can be installed.